# How to run a Coded UI test on a machine without VS2010 ultimate

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have created a CodedUI test in VS2010 (Ultimate) and called this test from 
a console application (which is built in the same .Net Framework 4).This is running fine on my machine or any other machine with VS2010 Ultimate installed.
When I try to run the CodedUI test on a 32-bit machine without VS2010 Ultimate it throws the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException: Cannot perform '' on the control. Additional Details: 
The control details were not specified. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {6DA215C2-D80D-42F2-A
514-B44A16DCBAAA} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.InitPlayback()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, IPlaybackContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize()
   at CitrixLANConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\<username>\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CitrixLANConsole\CitrixLANConsole\Program.cs:
line 27.
```

Can anyone tell me how can I make the test run on a machine which does not have VS2010 Ultimate installed on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in platform target: you are trying to run the `x64` code on `32-bit` system. Change the `Target Platform` for your application and run tests again.

The reason of the problem is that you are trying to manipulate the wrong class in your tests.

---

Hmm, I think that there is something in `Ultimate` package you can't get on other machine. Can't say for sure from your stacktrace, but try to find the class you're missing and put library with it in [`GAC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx).

The reason why the `regsvr32` didn't is that .NET libraries try to find the needed one library in GAC, not in some register entries. See more on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have built the file keeping target as x86, which is running fine in any machine which is 32bit and having VS2010 ultimate installed. I am getting this error only when I am trying to run it on a 32bit machine which is not having VS2010 ultimate installed. Can you please suggest something about how I can overcome this error and run my .exe on any 32bit machine. I even tried registering the .dll file using regsvr32 but I am getting the error ‘entry point of DllRegisterServer was not found’